# Checkbox Checked to remove a child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and removing a child div and it's controls from it's parent. I first attempted to use this method:

```js
  $("[id^=SelectedUser]:checked").each(function () {
        //.val() contains numberical index of div to remove. 
        $('#SUser' + $(this).val()).remove();
      });
```

But that does not remove the element.

I found this works:

```js
 $("[id^=SelectedUser]:checked").each(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      });
```

Can anyone explain to me why my original concept does not work?

Comment: can you post your code so we know the javascript is using right ids

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` this is not a child div as announced into the title ?

Comment: Verified i am using correct ID's. Will post HTML shortly

Answer (score 0):

`$this.val()` is returning the value of the check box. Are you sure that those numbers are coinciding with your div's ID? Seems to be the only thing I can find "wrong" with your code. Also your numerical value is in a string format correct not an integer Correct?

Comment: I verified ID's do match when children are generated. integer values of checkbox controls are in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html.

This generates the child div tags which contain user information. These are loaded into a static div with an ID of "SelectedSelections."

```js
 $("#SelectedSelections").append("<div id='SUser" + counter + "' class='SelectedUsersRow'><div class='RowControl'><input type='checkbox' id='SelectedUser" + counter + "' value='" + index + "' onclick='enableDisableButtons(\"REMOVESELECTIONS\");'/></div><div class='RowContent'>" + $("#displayString" + index).html() + "</div>" +
                     "<input type='Hidden' id='slastName" + counter + "' value='" + $("#lastName" + index).val() + "' />" + "<input type='Hidden' id='sCalledName" + counter + "' value='" + $("#CalledName" + index).val() + "' />" +
                     "<input type='Hidden' id='sEmail" + counter + "' value='" + $("#Email" + index).val() + "' />" + "<input type='Hidden' id='sDom" + counter + "' value='" + $("#Dom" + index).val() + "' />" +
                     "<input type='Hidden' id='sID" + counter + "' value='" + $("#ID" + index).val() + "' />" + "<input type='Hidden' id='sPhone" + counter + "' value='" + $("#Phone" + index).val() + "' /></div>");
```